# Sum of time differences of unknown number of rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I need to get the sum of times difference of unknown number of date rows. I can get the sum of that list using,

`SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME(o.discontinued_date)))`.

But I need to get the sum of the time differences. As an example,

```
2014-09-24 01:17:28
2014-09-24 01:17:41
2014-09-24 01:17:48
```

answer for this list should be `00:00:20`

But in my case I do not know the number of rows. I do not know what should I do to get the sum of differences. Please help. Sorry for my English. If you need more details please comment.
Thank you

Comment: max(o.discontinued_date) - min(o.discontinued_date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly.. it doesn't matter whether you have 2 rows or 20, since you are only intrested in the smallest and biggest time.

So you query should be very simple:

```
SELECT max(discontinued_date) - min(discontinued_date)
FROM YourTable;
```

In case you want to do it for each id/day or I dont know, you should use group by like this:(I.E. sum per day)

```
SELECT discontinued_date,max(discontinued_date) - min(discontinued_date)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY discontinued_date;
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. I didn't realized it. Thank you very much.